Submap-homeomorphisms and fundamental coverings
While solving one of the chapters of "Elementary Topology" Viro encountered the following problem:
Let $X$ and $Y$ be two topological spaces equipped with fundamental covers: $X=\bigcup_\alpha X_\alpha, Y=\bigcup_\alpha Y_\alpha$. Suppose $f: X\rightarrow Y$ is a map such that $f(X_\alpha)=Y_\alpha$ for each $\alpha$ and the submap $ab(f):X_\alpha \rightarrow Y_\alpha$ is a homeomorphism. Then $f$ is homeomorphism.
Now the definitions:

We say a cover $R$ is fundamental if $U⊆X $is open $⟺U∩A$ is open in $A$ with the subspace topology  $∀A∈R$.

If $A ⊂ X$ and $B ⊂ Y$ , then for every $f : X → Y$ such that $f(A) ⊂ B $ we have a map $ab(f) : A → B : x \mapsto f(x)$, which is called the abbreviation of $f$ to $A$ and $B$, a submap, or a submapping


I was trying to do something like that: first, we take the open set $U\subset X$. Since the covering $\bigcup_\alpha X_\alpha$ is fundamental, then $U\cap X_\alpha$ is open in $X_\alpha$. Consider the homeomorphism $ab(f):X_\alpha \rightarrow Y_\alpha$. Since homeomorphism bijectively maps open sets into open sets, the image $ab(f)(U\cap X_\alpha)$ is open in $Y_\alpha$. And this is true for every $Y_\alpha$. That is, we obtain that $f(U)$ is open in all $Y_\alpha$ (to be honest, now i think that may not be true, partly because $X_\alpha$'s are not necessarily non-intersecting). Since $\bigcup_\alpha Y_\alpha$ is fundamental, we get that $f(U)$ is open in $Y$. But then what? We have shown that open sets are mapped to open sets, but there is no bijectivity.
I tried another approach and tried to prove directly, that starting conditions imply surjectivity and injectivity of $f$, but couldn't manage to prove injectivity. It would be enough, because we know, that if the contraction of the mapping $f: X\rightarrow Y$ to every element of the fundamental covering $Г$ is continuous, then the mapping $f$ itself is continuous.

What is a "fundamental cover?" What is a "submap?" What is $ab(f)$? All these are nonstandard.

I edited the original question, so.it includes these definitions.

And the exercise you are trying to solve is simply false. Namely, take $X=Y=S^1\subset \mathbb C$, $f(z)=z^2$, $X_\alpha$'s are open arcs of length $\pi$ and $Y_\alpha$'s are open arcs of length $2\pi$ (complements to singletons).

I guess, you are right. Maybe we could impose some additional conditions, so the statement would be true?

Maybe if you assume that $f$ induces an isomorphism of nerves of the covers. But you probably do not even know what this means...

Or just assume that $f$ is a bijection.

Let $S^1$ denote the unit circle in the complex plane; I will equip $S^1$ with the angular metric. Let $B(z,r)\subset S^1$ denote the open ball of radius $r$ centered at $z\in S^1$ with respect to this metric. Let $Z\subset S^1$ denote the set of cube roots of unity (roots of the polynomial $z^3$). Define two open covers of $S^1$, both indexed by the elements of $Z$:

$U_a=B(a,\frac{\pi}{2})$, $a\in Z$.

$V_a= B(a,\pi)$, $a\in Z$.


Let $X=Y=S^1$ and consider the map $f: X\to Y$, $f(z)=z^2$. Then $f(U_a)=V_{a^2}$ and $f: U_a\to V_{a^2}$ is a homeomorphism
for all $a\in Z$. However, $f$ is obviously not a homeomorphism. Thus, the problem is false as stated. Most likely, the authors forgot to assume that $f$ is a bijection. With this extra assumption, you already have a solution.

I appreciate Moishe Kohan's reply and i also managed to come up with perhaps a slightly more intuitive or straightforward example:
Let $X$ be the union of the intervals $(0,1)$ and $(2,3)$ and our covering will be by the same intervals (open covering is always fundamental). Now let $Y$ be the interval $(0, 3)$ and for its covering we take intervals $(0,2)$ and $(1,3)$ and we define our mapping $f$ by "gluing" together two obvious homeomorphisms $g: (0,1) \rightarrow (0,2)$ and $h:(2,3) \rightarrow (1,3)$. Obviously, our $f$ is not injective, however it satisfies our conditions.
